# Pipe urls from xml into seperate file in Linux, using sed, awk, cat or grep

Tags: xml, linux, awk, sed, grep

I have an xml file with many products in it as per the xml example below.

I want to grep out all the urls in this document and pipe them into a new document. For example I want get the url between:

```
<url></url>
```

and pipe these into a new txt file with each url on a new line. So the output would look like a list of the urls like:

```
http://www.example.com/nav/rooms/kitchens/kitchen-worktops/gemstone_solid_surface_worktops/-specificproducttype-worktops/Cooke-and-Lewis-Gemstone-Triassic-Worktop-3050mm-13128613
http://www.example.com/nav/fix/nails-screws-fixings-hardware/furniture-hardware/legs___supports/-specificproducttype-furniture_legs/Rothley-Furniture-Leg-Angled-L501XN-Brushed-Nickel-Effect-H128mm-9281999
http://www.example.com/nav/fix/electrical/cable-management/cable_clips/Corelectric-Clips-Cable-Round-Polybag-Pk20-11348134
http://www.example.com/nav/fix/power-tool-accessories/router-bits/jointing_biscuits/Trend-T-Tech-Beech-Biscuit-No-10-TT-BSC-10-100-Pack-9288386
etc...
```

Here is an example of the xml, this repeats many times for lots of products:

```
<product>
                          <id>13128613</id>
                          <name>Cooke &amp; Lewis Gemstone Triassic Worktop 3050mm</name>
                          <categoryId>9372151</categoryId>
                          <features>Edged 1 long, 2 short sides, No templating required reducing fitting complexities, time and cost, This stunning design is made from 85% recycled material including glass and shell, supporting environmental sustainability, A 6mm solid material bonded to a 28mm solid chipboard core, backed with a moisture resistant balance paper for complete water resistance, A hard surface that is resistant to daily wear and tear</features>
                          <url>http://www.example.com/nav/rooms/kitchens/kitchen-worktops/gemstone_solid_surface_worktops/-specificproducttype-worktops/Cooke-and-Lewis-Gemstone-Triassic-Worktop-3050mm-13128613</url>
                          <productHierarchy>Rooms &gt; Kitchens &gt; Kitchen Worktops &gt; Gemstone Solid Surface Worktops &gt; Worktops</productHierarchy>
                          <quantity/>
                          <sku>
                                    <id>13619319</id>
                                    <name>Cooke &amp; Lewis Gemstone Triassic Worktop 3050mm</name>
                                    <description>A 6mm solid material bonded to a 28mm high performance chipboard core, Cooke &amp; Lewis Gemstone is the perfect green choice, formulated with 85% recycled material.</description>
                                    <ean>5397007119039</ean>
                                    <condition>new</condition>
                                    <price>582.00</price>
                                    <wasPrice/>
                                    <deliveryCost>0.0</deliveryCost>
                                    <deliveryTime>Delivery usually within 5 weeks</deliveryTime>
                                    <stockAvailability>1</stockAvailability>
                                    <skuAvailableInStore>0</skuAvailableInStore>
                                    <skuAvailableOnline>1</skuAvailableOnline>
                                    <channel>Home Delivery Only</channel>
                                    <buyerCats>
                <catLevel0>KITCHENS</catLevel0>
                <catLevel1>SOLID SURFACE WORKTOPS</catLevel1>
                <catLevel2>SPEEDSTONE SOLID SURFACE</catLevel2>
            </buyerCats>
                                    <affiliateCats>
                <affiliateCat0>Home &amp; Garden</affiliateCat0>
            </affiliateCats>
                                    <manufacturersPartNumber/>
                                    <specificationsModelNumber/>
                                    <featuresBrand>Cooke &amp; Lewis Gemstone</featuresBrand>
                                    <imageUrl>http://example.com/is/image/5397007119039_001c_v001_zp</imageUrl>
                                    <thumbnailUrl>http://example.com/is/image/5397007119039_001c_v001_zp?$75x75_generic$=</thumbnailUrl>
                                    <skuNavAttributes>
                                              <ecoGrowFoods>false</ecoGrowFoods>
                                              <ecoDLME>false</ecoDLME>
                                              <ecoRecycle>false</ecoRecycle>
                                              <ecoSavesWater>false</ecoSavesWater>
                                              <ecoHealthyHomes>false</ecoHealthyHomes>
                                              <ecoNurtureNature>false</ecoNurtureNature>
                                              <ecoSavesEnergy>false</ecoSavesEnergy>
                                    </skuNavAttributes>
                          </sku>
                </product>
```

I only want to get the main url of the product, I am not concerned with the other urls in the xml structure like the imageUrl and thumbnailUrl.

I have tried:

```
sed -rn '/<url>([^"]*)<\/url>/' file.xml > file.txt
```

however so far empty output.

Comment: did you try `grep`? how did it work?

Comment: I have tried with sed but so far empty output. I don't think my regex skills are up to the job. I have added an example of what I have tried now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can first grep for the `<url>` line (if the XML file is formatted like you've shown) and finally remove the XML tags:

```
grep '<url>' file.xml | sed 's/.*>\([^<]*\)<.*/\1/' >> file.txt
```

you can remove the tags completely

```
grep '<url>' a.txt | sed 's/<\/*url>//g'
```

you can select the second column after replacing `<` and `>` with spaces:

```
grep '<url>' a.txt | tr '<>' ' ' | awk '{print $2}'
```

also, instead of using grep you can go with `xpath` to select the proper tag, e.g. like this

```
xpath -q -e '//product/url' file.xml | ... > file.txt
```